# Restrict certain roles registrations by domain

Tags: functions, user-roles, user-registration, domain, validation

I'm really stumped on this one. I have figured out how allow registration from certain email domains. However, I only want to restrict one user type. For example 'ROLE1' can register with any email address, but 'ROLE2 are limited to, lets say gmail & yahoo accounts.

This is what I currently have

```
        <?php
    /**
     * Handles/processes registration forms data.
     */

    add_action( 'user_register', '_hrb_user_register_role' );

    /**
     * Assigns the selected role to the user being registered.
     */
    function _hrb_user_register_role( $user_id ) {

        if ( empty( $_POST['role'] ) ) {
            return;
        }

        $valid_roles = array_keys( hrb_roles() );
        $role = $_POST['role'];

        // make sure we always get a valid role on registration
        if ( empty( $role ) || ! in_array( $role, $valid_roles ) ) {
            $role = HRB_ROLE_BOTH;
        }

        wp_update_user( array ( 'ID' => $user_id, 'role' => $role ) );
    }

/**
* Filter email by role.
*/

    if( $role = HRB_ROLE1 ) {
    function is_valid_email_domain($login, $email, $errors ){
         $valid_email_domains = array("gmail.com", "yahoo.com");// whitelist email domain lists
         $valid = false;
         foreach( $valid_email_domains as $d ){
         $d_length = strlen( $d );
         $current_email_domain = strtolower( substr( $email, -($d_length), $d_length));
         if( $current_email_domain == strtolower($d) ){
         $valid = true;
         break;
         }
         }
         // if invalid, return error message
         if( $valid === false ){
         $errors->add('domain_whitelist_error',__( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: you can only register using gmail or yahoo email address!' ));
         }
        }
        add_action('register_post', 'is_valid_email_domain',10,3 );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to checkout the [`registration_errors`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/registration_errors/) filter. Make sure the role is being posted within the particular registration form.
Instead of conditionally adding your action you have to check within the filter if role and email are valid.

```
add_action( 'registration_errors', 'wpse_248123_registration_errors' );

function wpse_248123_registration_errors( $sanitized_user_login, $user_email, $errors ) {

  if ( empty( $_POST['role'] ) ) {
    $errors->add( 'empty_role', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: The role is invalid.' ) )
  }

  if ( 'ROLE1' === $_POST['role'] && !wpse_248123_is_valid_email_domain( $user_email ) ) {
    $errors->add( 'invalid_email_for_role', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: The email address isn&#8217;t allowed for this role.' ) )
  }

  return $errors;
}

function wpse_248123_is_valid_email_domain( $email = '' ) {

  $email = (string) $email;
  $valid = false;

  if ( empty( $email ) ) {
    return $valid;
  }

  $valid_email_domains = array("gmail.com", "yahoo.com");// whitelist email domain lists

  foreach( $valid_email_domains as $d ) {

    $d_length = strlen( $d );
    $current_email_domain = strtolower( substr( $email, -($d_length), $d_length ) );

    if( $current_email_domain === strtolower($d) ){
      $valid = true;
      break;
    }

  }

  return $valid;

}
```